# Counting the frequency of a factor in a list()

Tags: r

I have a list with 10 different list elements, each containing a sample of 20 breakfast items that can be reproduced here…

```
Diet <- as.factor(rep(c("Eggs","Meat","Eggs","Milk", "Juice"),20))

> head(Diet)
[1] Eggs  Meat  Eggs  Milk  Juice Eggs 
Levels: Eggs Juice Meat Milk
```

for() loop creating the 10 list elements.

```
  breakfast <- list()
    for ( i in 1:10) {
        breakfast[[i]] <- sample(Diet,20)
        }
```

For each list element 1:10 I am trying to count the number of times “Eggs” occurs.  This is a seemingly simple task, but I must be searching the wrong key words on other SO posts as I am getting little help from Goog et al.

I think the best option would be to add something like

```
NumEggs <- length(breakfast[[i]]==”Eggs”
```

to the `for()` loop but this code is incorrect and returns the full length (i.e. 20) rather than only the length of “Eggs.”

Any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
> sapply(breakfast, function(x)sum(x=="Eggs"))
 [1] 10  9 11  6  9  8  8  7  7 10
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're wondering why your own attempt didn't work, it's because

```
length(breakfast[[i]]=="Eggs")
```

is actually measuring the length of a logical vector, which in your case will always be 20:

```
breakfast[[9]]=="Eggs"
 [1] FALSE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE FALSE  TRUE FALSE
[13]  TRUE FALSE  TRUE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE FALSE  TRUE
```

You can use:

```
length(which(breakfast[[i]]=="Eggs"))
```

to check the length of the vector made from only the TRUE values. Sum like user1981275 suggested also works as summing will treat TRUE as 1 and FALSE as 0.